# In what function space is the fractional Laplacian $(-\Delta)^su$ essentially bounded?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, regularity-theory-of-pdes, fractional-calculus, nonlinear-analysis

Can it be said that if $u(x)=O(|x|^\beta)$, with $\beta\geq N+2s$, for $x\in\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^N$ a bounded domain, then $(-\Delta)^su\in L^{\infty}(\Omega)$?. Is there a generalized result corresponding to this if true?. In other words what will be the space in which $u$ belongs to if $(-\Delta)^su\in L^{\infty}(\Omega)$?.

Comment: If $\Omega$ is bounded, what is the point of talking about $O(|x|^\beta)$ at all?

Answer (score 1):

Whatever **size** restriction one has on $u$ do not imply its *smoothness*  and smoothness is reflected in the size of the Laplacian.  So the answer is negative regardless of $\beta$.

The inverse of $(-\Delta)^s$ is convolution with [Riesz kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz_potential) $|x|^{-2s}$. So the space of functions such that $(-\Delta)^su\in L^{\infty}(\Omega)$ is precisely the *Riesz potential space* (look it up) $I_{2s}(L^\infty)$. On a bounded domain, the Riesz potential is comparable to [Bessel potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_potential), which is more widely used.

Bessel potential inverts $(I-\Delta)^s$ but the distinction matters mostly for infinity. Unfortunately $p=\infty$ is a hairy case, and I believe the space of Bessel potentials of $L^\infty$ functions will be slightly larger than the fractional Sobolev space $W^{2s,\infty}$, but it should be "close" to it.

A comprehensive reference is [On spaces of potentials connected with $L^p$ classes](https://eudml.org/doc/73808) by Aronszajn, Mulla, and Szeptycki.